# Python error while connecting to cloud sql from cloud functions

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, google-cloud-functions, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to use `Python` code to connect from `GCP Cloud functions` to `PostgreSQL` instance of `CloudSQL` . I am new to `python` , so struggling with some error and need help to fix the error

My code is as follows:

```
# Don't add the "/.s.PGSQL.5432 suffix" because it will already be added back automatically by the library...
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:a1b2c3d4e190@X.X.X.X/postgres_dbase')
print("connected")
```

The function is deployed fine but the URL is failing with below error

```
  Error: could not handle the request
```

It is showing below error in the log

```
  Details:'Request' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

It works fine when I execute the code directly

```
   $ python3 open.py
    connected
```

I am using `Python 3.7`

**UPDATE**

It looks like I have to set DATABASE_URL but not sure how to set it in CLoud functions . Added below `Runtime environmental variable` in `Cloud functions` but no luck

```
 DATABASE_URL="sqlite://"
```

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5330

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are trying to connect from Public IP or from Private. However, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#public-ip-default_1) you can find an example about how to perform your concern using Public IP. Your code should looks  like

```
db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]
db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]
db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")
cloud_sql_connection_name = os.environ["CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME"]

pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(

    # Equivalent URL:
    # postgres+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>
    #                         ?unix_sock=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
        username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
        password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
        database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
        query={
            "unix_sock": "{}/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(
                db_socket_dir,  # e.g. "/cloudsql"
                cloud_sql_connection_name)  # i.e "<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>"
        }
    ),
    **db_config
)
```

On the other hand, if you are using Private IP, you should have in your code something like this

```
db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]
db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]
db_host = os.environ["DB_HOST"]

# Extract host and port from db_host
host_args = db_host.split(":")
db_hostname, db_port = host_args[0], int(host_args[1])

pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    # Equivalent URL:
    # postgres+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
        username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
        password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
        host=db_hostname,  # e.g. "127.0.0.1"
        port=db_port,  # e.g. 5432
        database=db_name  # e.g. "my-database-name"
    ),
    **db_config
)
```

Make sure you have configured your Cloud Functions depending on if you are using [Public IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#public-ip-default) or [Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#private-ip).

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for my connecting Google App Engine to PostgreSQL instance from Google Cloud Platform.

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='your_data_base_name', user='your_data_base_user', password='your_data_base_user_password', host='/cloudsql/project_name:region:database_instance_name')

except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print("Error: Could not make connection to the Postgres database")
    print(e)
cur = conn.cursor()
```